# Show/Hide Effects reload ajax elements inside

Tags: jquery

I want to used **blind** effect on my script, but if i call **show blind** it start to reload my ajax elements (which already was loaded) inside hidden div #searchbar

```
if (show == "false"){   
    $('#topbanner').hide("blind", 400);
    $('#search_bar').show("blind", 400);
       show = "true";

 }else{
    $('#search_bar').hide("blind", 400);
    $('#topbanner').show("blind", 400);
    show = "false";
 }
```

it's working fine with `$('#search_bar').show();` and `$('#search_bar').hide();`

Comment: Are you sure sure `jQuery-ui` is loaded ?

Comment: Effects are not included in jQuery core. They are included in jQuery UI so make sure you have it available on your page. If you already have it on your page, then there may be another problem. Try giving us a peek of your console.

Comment: yes jQuery UI is loaded, and effects working fine.